# Best way to do 3d transluscent planes

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot

I am trying to replace a diagram I made in powerpoint with something that I am making in tikz-3dplot.  The diagram should look similar to this

[image]

The problem that I'm running into is that the lines are falling entirely in front of or behind the right most plane

[image: What I've got]

So my question is, what is the best way to go about achieving this?  I know from looking around a little while ago that the issue is that tikz-3dplot actually converts everything to 2 dimensions so it would be pretty much impossible for it to know where the intersection occurs.  This is the same issue powerpoint has and what I did was create two different line segments and layer that way. Is there an easy way to do do this in tikz-3dplot?  Is there a better way entirely?

The code I used to generate the bottom plot follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\newcommand{\rotateRPY}[3]% roll, pitch, yaw
{   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rollangle}{#1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\pitchangle}{#2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yawangle}{#3}

    % to what vector is the x unit vector transformed, and which 2D vector is this?
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newxx}{cos(\yawangle)*cos(\pitchangle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newxy}{sin(\yawangle)*cos(\pitchangle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newxz}{-sin(\pitchangle)}
    \path (\newxx,\newxy,\newxz);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\nxx}{\nxy};

    % to what vector is the y unit vector transformed, and which 2D vector is this?
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newyx}{cos(\yawangle)*sin(\pitchangle)*sin(\rollangle)-sin(\yawangle)*cos(\rollangle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newyy}{sin(\yawangle)*sin(\pitchangle)*sin(\rollangle)+ cos(\yawangle)*cos(\rollangle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newyz}{cos(\pitchangle)*sin(\rollangle)}
    \path (\newyx,\newyy,\newyz);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\nyx}{\nyy};

    % to what vector is the z unit vector transformed, and which 2D vector is this?
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newzx}{cos(\yawangle)*sin(\pitchangle)*cos(\rollangle)+ sin(\yawangle)*sin(\rollangle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newzy}{sin(\yawangle)*sin(\pitchangle)*cos(\rollangle)-cos(\yawangle)*sin(\rollangle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newzz}{cos(\pitchangle)*cos(\rollangle)}
    \path (\newzx,\newzy,\newzz);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\nzx}{\nzy};
}


\newcommand{\translatepoint}[1]%
{   \coordinate (mytranslation) at (#1);
}

\tikzset{RPY/.style={x={(\nxx,\nxy)},y={(\nyx,\nyy)},z={(\nzx,\nzy)}}}

\tikzset{ultra thick/.style={line width=2.5pt}}

\newcommand\coordLength{0.5}
\newcommand\planeWidth{0.5}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}


\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,cm={-1,-1,1,0,(0,0)},x=1in,y=0.75in,z=-1in,>=stealth']
    %set up the axes so they are correctly oriented
    \rotateRPY{0}{0}{90}
    \begin{scope}[RPY]

        %create coordinates for various points of interest
        \coordinate (center) at (0,0,0);
        \coordinate (pp) at (0,0,1);
        \coordinate (fp) at (0,0,-1);
        %\coordinate (point) at (1,-1,3);
        \tdplotsetcoord{point}{3.5}{20}{-30};
        \coordinate (framew) at (-1,0,2.5);

        %Draw the camera coordinate frame
        \draw[->,thick] (center) -- ($(\coordLength,0,0)$);
        \draw[->,thick] (center) -- ($(0,\coordLength,0)$);
        \draw[->,thick] (center) -- ($(0,0,\coordLength)$);

        \node[inner sep=2pt] (cx) at ($(\coordLength+0.1,0,0)$) {\large$\textbf{c}_x$};
        \node[inner sep=2pt] (cy) at ($(0,\coordLength+0.1,0)$) {\large$\textbf{c}_y$};
        \node[inner sep=2pt] (cz) at ($(0,0.05,\coordLength+0.1)$) {\large$\textbf{c}_z$};

        %label the camera center
        \node[inner sep=2pt] (C) at ($(center)-(0.05,0.05,0.05)$) {\large$C$};
%
        %draw the principal axis
        \draw[dotted] (fp) -- (0,0,4);


        %draw the focal plane 
        \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=-1]
            \path[fill=lightgray,opacity=0.8,line join=round] (-\planeWidth,-\planeWidth) rectangle (\planeWidth,\planeWidth);
        \end{scope}

        %draw the world axes
        \rotateRPY{0}{10}{75}
        \begin{scope}[shift=(framew),RPY]

            %Draw the world coordinate frame
            \draw[->,thick] (0,0,0) -- ($(\coordLength+0.1,0,0)$);
            \draw[->,thick] (0,0,0) -- ($(0,\coordLength+0.1,0)$);
            \draw[->,thick,dashed] (0,0,0) -- ($(0,0,\coordLength-0.1)$);

            \node[inner sep=2pt] (wz) at ($(\coordLength+0.25,0,0)$) {\large$\textbf{w}_z$};
            \node[inner sep=2pt] (wy) at ($(0,\coordLength+0.25,0)$) {\large$\textbf{w}_y$};
            \node[inner sep=2pt] (wx) at ($(0,-0.05,\coordLength)$) {\large$\textbf{w}_x$};


        \end{scope}

        %draw the point and show the vectors to/from it
        \draw[ultra thick, ->] (framew) -- (point) node[circle,fill,inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt] {};

        \draw[ultra thick, ->] (center) -- (point);

        \node[inner sep=2pt] (x) at ($(point)+(0,0.08,0.08)$){\large $x$};


        %draw the image plane
        \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=1]
            \path[fill=lightgray,opacity=0.8,line join=round] (-\planeWidth,-\planeWidth) rectangle (\planeWidth,\planeWidth);
        \end{scope}

    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Note that I am not asking anyone to complete the drawing for me (although if you're bored and what something to do be my guest...) I simply want to know how to replicate the effect of the lines passing through the plane in tikz-3dplot.  Also note that unless it is drastically simpler I would rather not switch to a package that requires me to compile some way other than pdflatex, although if someone gives me a really good reason why I should do this I'll consider it.

Thanks.

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally figured it out while actually working on another diagram.  What I did is created two macros, one to go from cartesian to spherical coordinates and then one to go from spherical to cartesian coordinates.  By doing this, I could define points on the image plane in 3 space, convert these points to spherical coordinates, lengthen the points by lengthening rho, and then convert back to cartesian points and plot.  This then gave me a point on the image plane (or photo plane in this diagram) which I could draw a line to from the center before I drew the image plane, and then a point past the image plane which I could draw a line to after I drew the image plane.  The macros follow:

```
\newcommand{\xyztortp}[3]
{   \pgfmathsetmacro{\xcoord}{#1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ycoord}{#2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\zcoord}{#3}

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rhoCoord}{((\xcoord)^(2.0)+(\ycoord)^(2.0)+(\zcoord)^(2.0))^(0.5)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\phiCoord}{ifthenelse((\ycoord)<0,-acos(\zcoord/(\rhoCoord)),acos(\zcoord/(\rhoCoord)))}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\thetaCoord}{acos(\xcoord/(\rhoCoord*sin(\phiCoord))} 
}

\newcommand{\rtptoxyz}[3]
{   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rhoCoord}{#1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\thetaCoord}{#2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\phiCoord}{#3}

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xCoord}{\rhoCoord*sin(\phiCoord)*cos(\thetaCoord)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yCoord}{\rhoCoord*sin(\phiCoord)*sin(\thetaCoord)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\zCoord}{\rhoCoord*cos(\phiCoord)}
}
```

For anyone who may be interested the full code used to generate this figure follows:

```
\newcommand{\rotateRPY}[3]% roll, pitch, yaw
{   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rollangle}{#1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\pitchangle}{#2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yawangle}{#3}

    % to what vector is the x unit vector transformed, and which 2D vector is this?
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newxx}{cos(\yawangle)*cos(\pitchangle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newxy}{sin(\yawangle)*cos(\pitchangle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newxz}{-sin(\pitchangle)}
    \path (\newxx,\newxy,\newxz);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\nxx}{\nxy};

    % to what vector is the y unit vector transformed, and which 2D vector is this?
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newyx}{cos(\yawangle)*sin(\pitchangle)*sin(\rollangle)-sin(\yawangle)*cos(\rollangle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newyy}{sin(\yawangle)*sin(\pitchangle)*sin(\rollangle)+ cos(\yawangle)*cos(\rollangle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newyz}{cos(\pitchangle)*sin(\rollangle)}
    \path (\newyx,\newyy,\newyz);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\nyx}{\nyy};

    % to what vector is the z unit vector transformed, and which 2D vector is this?
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newzx}{cos(\yawangle)*sin(\pitchangle)*cos(\rollangle)+ sin(\yawangle)*sin(\rollangle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newzy}{sin(\yawangle)*sin(\pitchangle)*cos(\rollangle)-cos(\yawangle)*sin(\rollangle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newzz}{cos(\pitchangle)*cos(\rollangle)}
    \path (\newzx,\newzy,\newzz);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\nzx}{\nzy};
}

\newcommand{\xyztortp}[3]
{   \pgfmathsetmacro{\xcoord}{#1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ycoord}{#2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\zcoord}{#3}

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rhoCoord}{((\xcoord)^(2.0)+(\ycoord)^(2.0)+(\zcoord)^(2.0))^(0.5)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\phiCoord}{ifthenelse((\ycoord)<0,-acos(\zcoord/(\rhoCoord)),acos(\zcoord/(\rhoCoord)))}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\thetaCoord}{acos(\xcoord/(\rhoCoord*sin(\phiCoord))} 
}

\newcommand{\rtptoxyz}[3]
{   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rhoCoord}{#1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\thetaCoord}{#2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\phiCoord}{#3}

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xCoord}{\rhoCoord*sin(\phiCoord)*cos(\thetaCoord)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yCoord}{\rhoCoord*sin(\phiCoord)*sin(\thetaCoord)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\zCoord}{\rhoCoord*cos(\phiCoord)}
}

\newcommand{\translatepoint}[1]%
{   \coordinate (mytranslation) at (#1);
}

\tikzset{RPY/.style={x={(\nxx,\nxy)},y={(\nyx,\nyy)},z={(\nzx,\nzy)}}}

\tikzset{ultra thick/.style={line width=2.5pt}}




\tdplotsetmaincoords{30}{120}


\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,cm={-1,-1,1,0,(0,0)},x=1in,y=0.75in,z=-1in,>=stealth']
    %set up the axes so they are correctly oriented
    \rotateRPY{0}{0}{90}
    \begin{scope}[RPY]

        %create coordinates for various points of interest
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\planeDist}{1.5}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xbp}{-0.25}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ybp}{-0.15}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\coordLength}{0.35}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xpp}{0.2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ypp}{0.3}

        \coordinate (center) at (0,0,0);
        \coordinate (cp) at (0,0,\planeDist);
        \coordinate (cf) at (0,0,-\planeDist);
        \coordinate (bp) at (\xbp,\ybp,\planeDist);
        \coordinate (poip) at (\xpp,\ypp,\planeDist);
        \coordinate (poif) at (-\xpp,-\ypp,-\planeDist);


        \pgfmathsetmacro{\planeWidth}{0.5}

        %draw the focal plane and everything that touches it
        \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=-\planeDist]
            \path[fill=lightgray,opacity=0.8,line join=round,draw=black] (-\planeWidth,-\planeWidth) rectangle (\planeWidth,\planeWidth);

            \pgfmathsetmacro{\fcoordLength}{0.225}
            \draw[->,thick] (0,0) -- (\fcoordLength,0) node[anchor=north]{$\textbf{f}_y$};
            \draw[->,thick] (0,0) node[anchor=south]{$F$} -- (0,\fcoordLength) node[anchor=north]{$\textbf{f}_x$};

            \draw plot[mark=*, mark size=0.5] coordinates{(-\ypp,-\xpp)} node[anchor=north]{$\textbf{x}_F$};
        \end{scope} 

        \draw[decorate,decoration={brace, amplitude=6mm}] (0,0,0)--(0,0,-\planeDist) node[midway,below=6mm]{$f$};

        \draw[dashed] (poif) -- (center);

        \node[inner sep=2pt,anchor=south east] (fplabel) at (-\coordLength,-\coordLength-0.2,-\planeDist){Focal Plane};

        %Draw the camera coordinate frame
        \draw[->,thick] (center) -- ($(\coordLength,0,0)$);
        \draw[->,thick] (center) -- ($(0,\coordLength,0)$);
        \draw[->,thick] (center) -- ($(0,0,\coordLength)$);

        \node[inner sep=2pt] (cx) at ($(\coordLength+0.1,0,0)$) {$\textbf{c}_x$};
        \node[inner sep=2pt] (cy) at ($(0,\coordLength+0.1,0)$) {$\textbf{c}_y$};
        \node[inner sep=2pt] (cz) at ($(0,0.08,\coordLength+0.1)$) {$\textbf{c}_z$};

        %draw the vector between the camera center and image plane that connects to the B coordinate system
        \draw[<-,thick] (center) node[anchor=south west]{$\textbf{t}_B$} -- (bp);

        %draw the vector between the camera center and image plane that connects to the point of interest
        \draw[thick] (center) -- (poip);

        %label the camera center
        \node[inner sep=2pt] (C) at ($(center)-(0.05,0.05,0.1)$) {$C$};
%
        %draw the principal axis
        \draw[dashed] (cf) -- (cp);

        %draw the boresight
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\borex}{-0.03}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\borey}{-0.05}
        \coordinate (borep) at (\borex,\borey,\planeDist);

        \draw[dashed,red,thick] (center) -- (borep); %node[above,text=red]{boresight} 


        \draw[decorate,decoration={brace, mirror,amplitude=6mm}] (0,0,0)--(0,0,\planeDist) node[midway,below=6mm]{$f$};

        %draw the camera field of view
%        \coordinate (fov1b) at (\planeWidth,\planeWidth,\planeDist);
%        \coordinate (fov2b) at (-\planeWidth,\planeWidth,\planeDist);
%        \coordinate (fov3b) at (-\planeWidth,-\planeWidth,\planeDist);
%        \coordinate (fov4b) at (\planeWidth,-\planeWidth,\planeDist);
%
%        \draw[dotted] (center) -- (fov1b);
%        \draw[dotted] (center) -- (fov2b);
%        \draw[dotted] (center) -- (fov3b);
%        \draw[dotted] (center) -- (fov4b); 



        %draw the photo plane
        \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=\planeDist] 
            \path[fill=lightgray,draw=black,opacity=0.8,line join=round] (-\planeWidth,-\planeWidth) rectangle (\planeWidth,\planeWidth);

            \draw plot [mark=*, mark size=0.5] coordinates{(0,0)} node[anchor=north west]{$\textbf{c}_P$}; 
            \draw plot [mark=*, mark size=0.5,mark options={color=red}] coordinates{(\borex,\borey)};
            \node[anchor=south west,text=red, inner sep=2pt] (boreOnP) at (\borex,\borey){$\textbf{p}_P$};
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\icoordLength}{0.225}
            \draw[->,thick] (-\planeWidth,-\planeWidth) -- ($(-\planeWidth+\icoordLength,-\planeWidth)$) node[anchor=north]{$\textbf{p}_y$};
            \draw[->,thick] (-\planeWidth,-\planeWidth) node[anchor=west]{$P$} -- ($(-\planeWidth,-\planeWidth+\icoordLength)$) node[anchor=north]{$\textbf{p}_x$};
            \draw[->,thick] (0,0) -- (\icoordLength,0) node[anchor=north]{$\textbf{i}_y$};
            \draw[->,thick] (0,0) node[anchor=south east]{$I$} -- (0,\icoordLength) node[anchor=north]{$\textbf{i}_x$};

            \draw plot [mark=*, mark size=0.5] coordinates{(\ypp,\xpp)} node[anchor=north]{$\textbf{x}_I\text{, }\textbf{x}_P$};

        \end{scope}


        %Extend our field of view lines
%        \pgfmathsetmacro{\extend}{1.5}
%        \xyztortp{\planeWidth}{\planeWidth}{\planeDist} 
%        \rtptoxyz{\extend*\rhoCoord}{\thetaCoord}{\phiCoord}
%        
%        \coordinate (fov1e) at (\xCoord,\yCoord,\zCoord);
%
%        \draw[dotted,->] (fov1b) -- (fov1e);
% 
%        \xyztortp{-\planeWidth}{\planeWidth}{\planeDist} 
%        \rtptoxyz{\extend*\rhoCoord}{\thetaCoord}{\phiCoord}
%        
%        \coordinate (fov2e) at (\xCoord,\yCoord,\zCoord);
%
%        \draw[dotted,->] (fov2b) -- (fov2e);
%
%        \xyztortp{-\planeWidth}{-\planeWidth}{\planeDist} 
%        \rtptoxyz{\extend*\rhoCoord}{\thetaCoord}{\phiCoord}
%
%        \coordinate (fov3e) at (\xCoord,\yCoord,\zCoord);
%
%        \draw[dotted,->] (fov3b) -- (fov3e);
%
%
%        \xyztortp{\planeWidth}{-\planeWidth}{\planeDist} 
%        \rtptoxyz{\extend*\rhoCoord}{\thetaCoord}{\phiCoord}
%
%        \coordinate (fov4e) at (\xCoord,\yCoord,\zCoord);
%
%        \draw[dotted,->] (fov4b) -- (fov4e);
%
        %extend the principal axis
        \draw[dashed] (cp) -- +(0,0,1.5*\planeDist);
        \node[anchor=north] (princlabel) at  (0,0,1.7*\planeDist){principal axis};

        %extend the boresight
        \xyztortp{\borex}{\borey}{\planeDist}
        \rtptoxyz{(\planeDist+1.5*\planeDist)/cos(\phiCoord)}{\thetaCoord}{\phiCoord}

        \coordinate (boree) at (\xCoord,\yCoord,\zCoord);

        \draw[dashed,red,thick] (borep) -- (boree);

        \rtptoxyz{\rhoCoord*4/6}{\thetaCoord}{\phiCoord}
        \node[anchor=south,text=red] (borelable) at (\xCoord,\yCoord,\zCoord) {boresight}; 

        %extend the line to the body fixed frame
        \xyztortp{\xbp}{\ybp}{\planeDist}
        \rtptoxyz{2*\rhoCoord}{\thetaCoord}{\phiCoord}

        \coordinate (bodyFrame) at (\xCoord,\yCoord,\zCoord);

        \draw[thick] (bp) -- (bodyFrame);


        %draw the world axes
        \rotateRPY{0}{10}{75}
        \begin{scope}[shift=(bodyFrame),RPY]

            %Draw the world coordinate frame
            \draw[->,thick] (0,0,0) -- ($(\coordLength+0.1,0,0)$);
            \draw[->,thick] (0,0,0) -- ($(0,\coordLength+0.1,0)$);
            \draw[->,thick] (0,0,0) -- ($(0,0,\coordLength-0.1)$);

            \node[inner sep=2pt] (wz) at ($(\coordLength+0.25,0,0)$) {$\textbf{b}_z$};
            \node[inner sep=2pt] (wy) at ($(0,\coordLength+0.25,0)$) {$\textbf{b}_y$};
            \node[inner sep=2pt] (wx) at ($(0,-0.05,\coordLength)$) {$\textbf{b}_x$};

            \node[inner sep=2pt] (B) at (-0.03,-0.03,-0.03) {$B$};


        \end{scope}

        %extend the poi line to the poi
        \xyztortp{\xpp}{\ypp}{\planeDist}
        \rtptoxyz{1.75*\rhoCoord}{\thetaCoord}{\phiCoord}

        \coordinate (poi) at (\xCoord,\yCoord,\zCoord);

        \path (poi) node[circle, fill, inner sep=1]{};

        \draw[thick,->] (poip) -- (poi) node[anchor=north east]{$\textbf{x}_C$};

        \draw[thick,->] (bodyFrame) -- (poi) node[anchor=west]{$\textbf{x}_B$};

        \node[inner sep=2pt,anchor=south east] (iplabel) at (-\coordLength,-\coordLength-0.2,\planeDist){Photo Plane};









    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

%        \node[inner sep=2pt] (blah) at (2,2,2) {\xcoord|\ycoord|\zcoord|\rhoCoord|\thetaCoord|\phiCoord};
```

which produces:

[image]