# Reorienting the pst-solides3d axes

Tags: pstricks, pst-solides3d

**EDIT:** I figured out how to make this diagram in tikz using the 3dplot package.  You can see what I did for that [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269319/best-way-to-do-3d-transluscent-planes).  I am still interested in this question however for potential future use so I will leave it open for now.

---

I am trying to learn pst-solides3d and use it to generate something like [image: desired diagram]

What I can't seem to figure out is how to rotate the axes so that z is to the right, x is coming out of the page, and y is down.

Is there a way to do this?

What little code I have so far is below.  I don't really want to continue if there's not an easy way to rotate the axes, I'll just figure out how to make something similar work in tikz...

You can compile this with a simple xelatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\psset{viewpoint=50 20 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=50}
\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-4,-4)(6,5)
\psset{unit=0.5}

\psSolid[object=plan,action=draw**,definition=equation,args={[0 0 1 -4]},
         base=-4 4 -4 4,fillcolor=black!15,fillstyle=solid,name=P0]
\psProjection[object=texte,fontsize=14,linecolor=red,text=Image Plane,phi=90,plan=P0]

\psSolid[object=plan,action=draw**,definition=equation,args={[0 0 1 4]},
         base=-4 4 -4 4,fillcolor=black!15,fillstyle=solid,name=P1]
\psProjection[object=texte,fontsize=14,linecolor=red,text=Focal Plane,phi=90,plan=P1]
\axesIIID(0,0,0)(10,10,10)

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide the code you are using.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina  I have added in what little code I have.  I haven't bothered to try to do too much till I find out whether it's possible to rotate the axes because that's something of a non-starter.  Yes I could always just draw my own axes but that would make things much more complicated than they need to be to draw everything else.